# Converting Fortran array to numpy array

Tags: numpy, fortran, numpy-ndarray, fortran90

I am in the process of converting a Fortran 90 code to python. The Fortran code includes multidimensional array like:

```
integer fvpair(3,12,2)
integer jpair(3,2)
real*8 aread(3,12)
```

I wonder if the following numpy array are correct equivalent, assuming zero initialization:

```
fvpair = np.array([[np.zeros(3)],[np.zeros(12)],[np.zeros(2)]])
jpair = np.array([[np.zeros(3)],[np.zeros(2)]])
aread = np.array([[np.zeros(3)],[np.zeros(12)]])
```

Comment: You probably want `fvpair = np.zeros((3,12,2), dtype=int)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve the original Fortran array storage order (column-major), do not forget to pass the `order='F'` flag!

```
fvpair = np.zeros((3,12,2), dtype=int, order='F')
jpair = np.zeros((3,2), dtype=int, order='F')
aread = np.zeros((3,2), dtype=float64, order='F')
```